# Web Scrape with a Mobile Web App?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, jquery-mobile

I recently created a native Android app and one feature it has is pulling some stats/data from an HTML table on a website using jsoup, formats it as a csv and finally pushes the data into a 2D array. The table is updated weekly so this data pull happens often and is not something I want to be manual. It works great but I now would like to create a mobile web app so it can be cross platform and not just Android. Is it possible to have this same functionality using only Javascript, CSS, and HTML5 in a mobile web app? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you will want to craft an API on your webserver that serves up the info you want from your database.

There are many, many ways to do that. My personal preference is crafting one by hand using PHP, but like I said there are several ways of doing this without having to recreate the wheel.

You can use a library like [Codeignitor](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)

OR you can use a service like [Kimono](https://www.kimonolabs.com/)

Regardless, it needs to be an API that serves up that data preferably as a JSON object.

You can then consume that data (into a view/template/html) via jQuery, Javascript, Backbone.js or Angular.js... take your pick.

Comment: I'm a little new to this but it seems like you made it a little more complicated than it actually is. I am not using any type of database just reading raw HTML from a site and pulling the table rows from the table and storing the values in an array.

Comment: OK, so you are using jsoup as your API to do the scraping. SO the answer to your question is YES. You can do that using only JS, HTML, CSS no problem. If you are not familiar with HOW. You might consider using a library like jQuery. It was made to do AJAX calls such as these then format them into nice little objects you can expose and use in a common web page format.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am slightly familiar with jQuery but not doing any type of web scraping or AJAX calls. Definitely going to try it out and do some more research. Do you think storing it in a database would be easier? It's a very small table and would only have 8 rows that are updated every week. I'm inexperienced with back-end development though.

Comment: I would use a database, just because it would be the most effective, and portable tool for the job.